# QGIS - Counting vertexes in radius from each feature in line layer

Tags: qgis, line, vertices, count, streets

I am looking to measure the impact of urban green on pedestrian route choice, and in that connection I want to create a new field within a line layer that counts how many trees exist in a radius of 10 meters from the center of each feature in the line layer. (could also be within the radius of 10 meters from the two extremes of the line, doesn't matter so much).

I am working in QGIS 3.4.13-Madeira.

Am at a total loss as to how to do this, and can't seem to find any articles that might point me in the right direction.

[image: urban green]

(the points are trees)

Comment: Well, you don't need to limit this to any vertice based radius; it's trivial to get a true line *proximity* count. However, it is crucial for us to know what software you are using; please edit the tags of your question to include it, and remember to limit it to a single piece (or stack) of software (i.e. not QGIS + ArcGiS)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've now done so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `roads` layer has no respective field yet:

- mark the layer and open the *Field Calculator*

  - toggle *Create a new field*
  - choose an *Output field name*
  - select *Output field type*: `Whole number (integer)`
  - paste this expression:
    `aggregate( '<tree_layer_name>', 'count', '', distance(  geometry( @parent ),  $geometry ) <= <dist> )`
    with `<tree_layer_name>` replaced with the actual name of the tree layer, and `<dist>` replaced with the search radius around the line feature
    **Note:**
    The `<dist>` value will be treated as **units of CRS**, meaning that, if your layers are referenced in EPSG:4326 (or any geographic reference), these will be **degrees**. For it to be treated as **meters**, make sure your layers are projected in a suitable **metric projection**!

Comment: Great, that worked - thanks heaps!

Comment: Just a question on the mechanics at work - does it count within the radius of the endpoints, or from the radius of each point on the line?

Comment: @Klaus_Asbjorn Glad it helped. It's the latter: a dot product distance between a line and a point, extended for a finite segment. If it solved your question consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer, that'd be nice ,)